# Converting a {classicthesis} book into a .doc file

Tags: formatting, conversion, classicthesis

I'm looking for a *free* (not shareware, because I have many files to convert and I don't want limits), stable, relatively simple way to convert my phd thesis coded using "ClassicThesis" package, into a .doc (Word) document, since one of my Committee's member explicitly requested this format. I have coded my thesis in separate files applying the package to each file for my convenient elaboration. 
Thus, I will convert each .tex into .doc.

Please help me, I am having hard times with this last moment news! 
I must deliver the thesis on Feb., 20th!
Many thanks in advance,

MChiara

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As @JuriRobl pointed out, this question has been asked before.

Comment: And unfortunately there isn't a great solution.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the committee member (politely) if (s)he really needs it in word format. (S)he could easily make notes on a pdf copy.

Comment: Here are [some arguments](http://www.goldmark.org/netrants/no-word/attach.html) to use with your Committee member.

Comment: Last time I had to do this, I made a word doc with no margins, and pasted the pages from my PDF output into it one at a time as full page images.  (But apparently that wasn't quite what they wanted... :-)

Comment: Thank you! I have also tried to convert the generated .pdf into a .doc, but obviously all my tables and graphs have been skipped! He says he wants to make comments directly on the file (but this could be done easily on the pdf as we know...) and he told me he "knows" (?!?) LaTeX and "he knows" that .tex file can be converted into a .doc by "forcing the software". Does he really know LaTeX and its features? I will see the argument suggested...

Comment: I guess there is not a complete solution for your problem, however, if you are willing to do some work of formatting, you could try to use `pandoc` to transform your LaTeX to `org` (this is a text markup language developed by `emacs` users) which can be exported to `ODT` format. After that, with your LibreOffice or OpenOffice suite, can be saved as `doc` file. Uffff... it sound hard, and additionally the exports might not be perfect, so you have to check each step!

Comment: Dear friends and helpers, the professor requested explicitly  a .doc file, no .odt, no .rtf, together with the .pdf -- don't ask me why! This is an odd situation.